# Define/call a function in isotope onLayout

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I'm using http://isotope.metafizzy.co/docs/options.html#onlayout and it says this:

"Similiar to a callback, onLayout is a function that will be triggered after every time an Isotope instance runs through its layout logic."

```
$('#container').isotope({
   onLayout: function( $elems ) {
    // `this` refers to jQuery object of the container element
    console.log( this.height() );
    // callback provides jQuery object of laid-out item elements
    $elems.css({ background: 'blue' });
    }
});
```

That means that when "Layout" has finished i can run this:

```
 $elems.css({ background: 'blue' });
```

I don't have "$elems" but from what i can understand that means that when "onLayout" has finished i can run what i want and I would like to run this:

```
$("#container").width(); 
$("#head").animate({ width: newWidth}, "fast");
```

But how and what is "$elems" inside the "( )" ?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not understanding what you want to do.  Are you trying to define an `onLayout` function that you can also call some other time?  If so, when else do you want to call it?  If not, please describe in more detail what you want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bind custom events on to elements like so:

```
$('#container').bind('my_event', function ()
{
    alert('my_event has just fired!');
});
```

And then call it with `.trigger()`:

```
$('#container').trigger('my_event');
```

Using this, you should be able to set up what you want pretty easily, I think.

---

Update:

Instead of calling this code:

```
$('#container').isotope({
   onLayout: function( $elems ) {
    // `this` refers to jQuery object of the container element
    console.log( this.height() );
    // callback provides jQuery object of laid-out item elements
    $elems.css({ background: 'blue' });
    }
});
```

Call this:

```
$('#container').isotope({
   onLayout: function( $elems ) {
        // `this` refers to jQuery object of the container element
        console.log( this.height() );
        // callback provides jQuery object of laid-out item elements
        $elems.css({ background: 'blue' });
        $("#container").width(); 
        $("#head").animate({ width: newWidth}, "fast");
    }
});
```

Comment: i need to run my bit exactly after this onLayout: function( $elems ) { as the example says

Comment: OK, `$elems` is a set of items being passed into the function. At a guess, it's going to be the elements which are being re-ordered by Isotope (it's pretty likely to be). As for how to do it, well, these are options so they're meant to be edited. Just add it in to the `onLayout` function, immediately after `$elems.css({ background: 'blue' });` and before the next `}`

Comment: ok so $elems are my ".box" in my case (not shown in the question) i see, so it isn't really a call back, because the bit of code i need to run isn't something to do with my ".box" (e.g. $elems). correct?

Comment: Not necessarily - you can do anything in `onLayout`, it doesn't have to only do things that work with `$elems`. That's just being passed in because another part of that function needs them. The main purpose of the function is to execute some code every time the layout is changed - if that's when you need to run your extra bit, it should go in that function.

Comment: rigth but that's exactly what i'm asking.. how can I? I did put in the question what I need to run, please help :)

Comment: oh man guess what it was? i didn't put a , after the closing } - i feel so stupid, obviously needed it as i have more options afterwards!

Comment: Heh, it's always the simple ones :) Just make sure that the last one **doesn't** have a comma after it - http://www.enterprisedojo.com/2010/12/19/beware-the-trailing-comma-of-death/