# Initializing prettyPhoto using Isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble initializing prettyPhoto now that I've switched from QuickSand to Mettafizzy Isotope.

Through posts here I've tried the code below with the onLayout function,
and by trying to bind and trigger

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236945/define-call-a-function-in-isotope-onlayout#*=*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9236945/define-call-a-function-in-isotope-onlayout#_=_)

I'm new to javascript/jQuery... so any help is much appreciated.

_Cindy

PS I'm using prettyPhoto for its social sharing features. Any other lightboxes with sharing features that anyone likes using -- I'd appreciated recommendations.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var $container = $('.gallery');
$container.isotope({
    filter: '*',
    animationOptions: {
    duration: 850,
        easing: 'linear',
      queue: false
    }
});

$('.gallery').isotope({
    onLayout: function() {
    $("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({ animationSpeed: 'slow', slideshow: 2000 });
    }
});

$('.filter ul li a').click(function(){
    $('.filer ul li .current').removeClass('current');
    $(this).addClass('current');

    var selector = $(this).attr('data-filter');
    $container.isotope({
        filter: selector,
        animationOptions: {
            duration: 850,
            easing: 'linear',
            queue: false
        }
     });
     return false;
});


});
```

Comment: I've read through Isotope's documentation, and have tried 'on' 'layoutComplete to trigger prettyPhoto after a layout. I'm also wondering if I need to initialize prettyPhoto with the filter feature... just a little documentation about how to use an image lightbox with isotope would help, but eventually I'll get there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All that was needed was to back down the version of JQuery to 1.8.3 and JQuery UI to 1.8.24 (higher versions may work, but this seemed optimal).

I initialize isotope as in the question above, no changes.

And initialized prettyPhoto as indicated below.

Now both isotope filtering and prettyPhoto Lightbox w social sharing are working together.

Changed my layoutmode for isotope to fitColumns since all columns were same width and that worked best for my responsive design.

```
$(function () {
// bind radiobuttons in the form
var $filterType = $('.filter li a');

// get the first collection
var $applications = $('#list');

// clone applications to get a second collection
var $data = $applications.clone();

// attempt to call Quicksand on every form change
$filterType.click(function (e) {

    $('.filter li a').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
    if ($(this).attr('id') == 'all') {
        var $filteredData = $data.find('li');
    } else {
        var $filteredData = $data.find('li[class=' + $(this).attr('id') + ']');
    }
    // finally, call quicksand
    $applications.quicksand($filteredData, {
        duration: 800,
        attribute: 'id'
    }, function () {
        $("a[data-rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({ animationSpeed: 'slow', slideshow: 2000 });
        });
    });

});
```